# Python: Don't find text

Tags: python, regex

This regular expression:

```
<span style=\"color: #008000;\" data-iceapw=\"1\">HIGH<\/span>
```

try to find this text:

```
<span style="color: #008000;" data-iceapw="1">HIGH<\span>
```

in a snipet of code like this, for example:

```
<p data-iceapw="9" data-iceapc="4">Factual Reporting: <strong data-iceapw="1" data-iceapc="1"><span style="color: #008000;" data-iceapw="1">HIGH</span><br />
</strong>World Press Freedom Rank: <span style="color: #ff9900;" data-iceapw="2" data-iceapc="1"><strong data-iceapw="2">USA 45/180</strong></span></p>
```

If we use this website to test it we can check that is correct: https://regex101.com/

But, when I try to do the same with Python, Python doesn't detect me this text:

```
<span style="color: #008000;" data-iceapw="1">HIGH<\span>
```

The code of python where I try to detect that text is:

```
re.search('<span style=\"color: #008000;\" data-iceapw=\"1\">HIGH<\/span>', str(soup), re.IGNORECASE)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit I:**

I don't understand why this regex works fine:

```
 re.search('<strong><span style=\"color: #008000;\">HIGH<br>\n<\/span><\/strong>', str(soup), re.IGNORECASE)
```

And find me the piece of code that I'm looking for. But, this other regex doesn't work:

```
re.search('<span style=\"color: #008000;\" data-iceapw=\"1\">HIGH<\/span>', str(soup))
```

When I try to find this:

```
<span style="color: #008000;" data-iceapw="1">HIGH</span>
```

In this code:

```
<p data-iceapw="9" data-iceapc="4">Factual Reporting: <strong data-iceapw="1" data-iceapc="1"><span style="color: #008000;" data-iceapw="1">HIGH</span><br />
</strong>World Press Freedom Rank: <span style="color: #ff9900;" data-iceapw="2" data-iceapc="1"><strong data-iceapw="2">USA 45/180</strong></span></p>
```

Comment: `\/` in your regex will not match ```\``` in your string.

Comment: Which HTML is closed with a backslash?

Comment: @JoséCarlos `<\span>` in the part after `Python doesn't detect me this text:`.. and in part after `try to find this text:` so unclear what your actual string is.

Comment: i don't understand because in other regex I have scaped "/" and it works to me but in this case it doesn't work. Which would be the correct way to do it?

Comment: A forward slash doesn't need to be escaped. In regex101 it does because they are using it as a delimiter. If you switch the flavor to `python` you will see it is not needed. It is unclear what your string has. Forward slashes and back seem interchanged.

Comment: So, If I want to detect this code: <span style="color: #008000;" data-iceapw="1">HIGH<\span> What would be the regex in python?

Comment: So the HTML really is closed with a backslash? If so you need to escape the backslash so it is read as literal, not as an escape character (ironic). Also, turns out python does need double quotes escaped (opps). https://regex101.com/r/aGvn2t/1/ There is really no need for regex here though.

Comment: Yes, this is the code that I want to find:  <span style="color: #008000;" data-iceapw="1">HIGH<\span>

Comment: That `<\span>` is malformed HTML. Are you sure that `str(soup)` returns such? Perhaps you should search for `</span>` instead?

Comment: Thanks @JustinEzequiel!!!! I didn't see it!!! It doesn't work to me :( I'm going to edit my original post with more examples.

Comment: Since you're searching `str(soup)`, perhaps you should post a copy-paste sample of that.

Comment: I can't paste all the code because it's too big. But in my update of the post I have posted a snippet of code where you can find this code and test it.

Comment: What was likely happening is BeautifulSoup is storing the attributes as an unordered dictionary and thus, the order was swapped when rendering to text via `str(soup)`. Another reason why using regular expressions is not the preferred method when searching HTML or XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a soup object so why not use that to search?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''\
<div>
<span>not this</span>
<span style="color: #008000;" data-iceapw="1">HIGH</span>
<span>nor this</span>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

matches = soup.select("span[data-iceapw='1']")
for span in matches:
    print(span)
```